# How to add another parameter to use in the php file while including a php file using shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I use shortcode to include a PHP-file into a WordPress page. That Works fine. But I need to add a parameter, not only the filename.

I can add another parameter in the shortcode, but I don't see, how I can give the other parameter (i.e. "title") to use it in the PHP-file.

Actual shortcode looks like `[include file=PATH.phpfile]`. I would add another parameter `title=titleexample`to use it in the PHP file.

I use this code to include the php-file (works fine):

```php
function include_shortcode_function($attrs, $content = null) {
    if (isset($attrs['file'])) {
        $file = strip_tags($attrs['file']);
        if ($file[0] != '/')
            $file = ABSPATH . $file;
        ob_start();
        include($file);
        $buffer = ob_get_clean();
        $options = get_option('includeme', array());
        if (isset($options['shortcode'])) {
            $buffer = do_shortcode($buffer);
        }
    }
    return $buffer;
}

add_shortcode('include', 'include_shortcode_function');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the shortcode attributes with known attributes and fills in defaults when needed.

```
  function include_shortcode_function($atts) {
        $attrs = shortcode_atts( array(
            'file' => '',
            'title'  =>  ''
        ), $atts );

       //Get the file and title details 
        $files = esc_attr($attrs['file']);
        $title = esc_attr($attrs['title']);

        if (isset($files)) {
            $file = strip_tags($files);
            if ($file[0] != '/')
                $file = ABSPATH . $file;
                //Use this variable in included file for title.
                $pagetitle = $title;
            ob_start();
            include($file);
            $buffer = ob_get_clean();
            $options = get_option('includeme', array());
            if (isset($options['shortcode'])) {
                $buffer = do_shortcode($buffer);
            }
        }
        return $buffer;

    }


add_shortcode('include', 'include_shortcode_function');
```

use the shortcode like.

```
[include file=PATH.phpfile title= titleexample]
```

Let's you include the example.php file. in example.php file use variable $pagetitle.

```
echo '<p class="title">'.$pagetitle.'</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But how can I use now the title in my php file?

Comment: In your included php file add the variable $pagetitle  like echo $pagetitle.